# Centered title inside of a subplot (matplotlib, pyplot)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, title, subplot

I have a 3x2 grid of equal sized plots. I use the command

```
plt.suptitle("Awesome title")     # (1)
```

to have a centered title above the 6 plots. I use the command

```
plt.title("Almost awesome title") # (2)
```

for a specific title above each subplot. Now the tricky part: I want a centered title between first and second row of subplots. After manipulating the position parameter of (2) to something like (1.1 , 1.0), I can not seem to get a properly/nicely formatted figure.

TL;DR: I want an additional `plt.suptitle("Title")` that be put as shown on picture below: (photoshopped)

[image: Arbitrary plot to illustrate point of centered titles inside subplots]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just make some extra room between rows, and add text:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.sca(axs[0,0])
plt.title('Sigmoid')
plt.sca(axs[0,1])
plt.title('ReLU')
plt.suptitle('Activation functions')

# Adjust vertical_spacing = 0.5 * axes_height
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

# Add text in figure coordinates
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.5, 'Effect of bias addition', ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, figure coordinates was new to me,- that solved it! Great!

Comment: but this means, everytime you add a new row of plots, you have to adjust all title positions, right?